# Trying to use ANT+ SDK for linux - error in make

Tags: makefile

I am trying to use the ANT SDK from thisiant website : [here](https://www.thisisant.com/developer/resources/downloads/), I unzip the folder, then I have a DEMO_LIB file with a Makefile on it. So in my console (from the folder) I run `sudo make` but I got an error. I have no idea where the error can come from. Do I have to change something in another file manually : `keys-from-name.h` maybe ? Thank you

```
  GEN    extras/keymap/keys-from-name.h
(standard input): No keywords in input file!
Makefile:3024: recipe for target 'extras/keymap/keys-from-name.h' failed
make[2]: *** [extras/keymap/keys-from-name.h] Error 1
make[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/ly81551h/Téléchargements/ANT-SDK_Linux_3.8.200_(BETA) (2)/ANT_LIB/udev-175 »
makefile:688: recipe for target 'create_folders' failed
make[1]: *** [create_folders] Error 2
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/ly81551h/Téléchargements/ANT-SDK_Linux_3.8.200_(BETA) (2)/ANT_LIB »
makefile:65: recipe for target 'lib' failed
make: *** [lib] Error 2
```

The SDK can be find here : [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VY9VpDxWxJ1saZtm_6mS5IuceO12XUSg)

Comment: Generally speaking, there is often a local configuration step required before one can successfully build a third-party package.  Sometimes a program is included in the source distribution to handle that, and other times you are expected to edit one or more files by hand (sometimes, but not always, the Makefile).  There should be documentation accompanying the source distribution (likely *in* it) describing the appropriate procedure for building it.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Ok, I do not find anything inside the folder except a Library folder and if I run make, I got the same error. IThe readme file do not help me that much. I have updated my post to able ones to get the SDK (end of the post). If you could take a look, I probably miss something... Thanks @JohnBollinger

Comment: I have no inside knowledge of this package, and I am not prepared to study it to try to guess what the appropriate prerequisites and procedure for building it may be.  If there really is no build documentation available (even separate from the download), nor any form of assistance available from the distributor, then I am inclined to think that they don't really want you to build the software from source in the first place.

Comment: ok thank for your help